# ng-container is not working inside the ionic2 component "ion-item-sliding"

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm trying to bind multiple conditions inside the `ion-item-sliding` ionic2 component using the following code:

```
<ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let member of members | async">
  <ng-container *ngIf="member?.info | async as info">
    <ng-container *ngIf="member?.status | async as status">
    <ion-item *ngIf="!status.deleted">
      {{info.email}} 
      <span class="status" *ngIf="member?.status | async as status">{{status.owner ? 'Owner' : status.guest ? 'Guest':'Admin'}}</span>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="right" *ngIf="checkEmail(info.email) || status.owner">
      <button ion-button class="trash" color="danger" (click)="kickUser(member.$value)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button ion-button *ngIf="member?.status | async as status" (click)="changeRole(member.$value,status.guest)">
        {{status.guest ? 'Change to admin' : 'Change to guest'}}
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</ion-item-sliding>
```

I didn't show any thing in the screen. so how to make the ng-container work?

Thanks.

Comment: member is not async, so you should not use the async pipe there.

Comment: member.info. and member.status are firebaseObjectObservable that y I used the async pipe @user3492940

Comment: thats where you are wrong. Only members is an Observable. Look at your line 1! *ngFor="let member of members | async". Or are you telling me your members observable returns an array of more observables? That would be extremely nasty to use in HTML.